# How to relax Matplotlib plot dimensions in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I want to compare two images using matplotlib in python. My code works but I want to resize the images to be the height of the colorbars.

```
plt.subplot(1, 2, 1)
plt.imshow(train_images[0])
plt.colorbar()
plt.subplot(1, 2, 2)
plt.imshow(train_images_prep[0])
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `imshow` makes the axis scaling to be equal in both dimensions, resulting in a square for your image. The height of the `colorbar` is the same as the height of the original axis before this rescaling. Instead of using the default figure size, you may start with a wider canvas to get the desired result:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))  # Dimensions in inches, play with the width
```

Play with the dimensions as required. I would also suggest using the object-oriented API instead:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(12,5))
first = axes[0].imshow(train_images[0])
second = axes[1].imshow(train_images_prep[0])
fig.colorbar(first, ax=axes[0])
fig.colorbar(second, ax=axes[1])
```